# Using build with TFS2010 on projects that use moles assemblies fail with -1002 as cannot resolve reference

Tags: tfs, pex, moles, pex-and-moles

After much playing i have managed to get TFS to be able to run builds on all of my projects except the test projects. These have a moles assembly in them.

The errors i am getting are

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\Microsoft.Moles.targets (79):
> The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe"
> @"C:\Builds\2\cv2\DevBranchBuild\Sources\CV.BL.Tests\obj\Release\Moles\moles.args""
> exited with code -1002.

The warning is

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1360):
> Could not resolve this reference.
> Could not locate the assembly "CV.DAL.Moles, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
> Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.
> If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

CV.DAL is the assembly i am moling.

I am using the latest version of pex and moles.

I also have the `CV.DAL.moles` file checked into TFS (not the assembly).
Everything builds perfectly fine on my local machine. The machine I am using to do the builds has exactly the same configuration. By exactly I mean that one is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit :o (serious oversight there).

Any ideas?

This makes pex and moles utterly useless as it is breaking gated checkins when merging branches which is a great shame as i invested a decent amount of time into them.

#### EDIT

Which molesAssemblies directories?
The install folder for moles or the directories under the project?
The installation folder has he same files and file sizes on both machines.

Comment: Dumb comment, but I you have installed the EXACT same version of Pex and Moles on your build machine.. right?  (We use Pex and Moles with our autobuild and usually when there is problems it is because the versions are not the same.)

Comment: Check to see if the MolesAssemblies folder is the same on your build machine and your local machine.  (The MolesAssemblies folder is under the test project.)  It should have the moles dlls in it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit, unfortunately that was a long time ago and i am now working on a completely different project. At the point i asked the question i wasn't using nuget so it would of been wherever the moles installer package (from microsoft research site iirc installed). So yes it would of been exact same versions (as same installer) and would of used default locations.

Answer (score 3):

This could be one of two problems -- I ran into both of them some time ago:

(one) One of your dependencies is marked as 32 bit. This might be cv.dal.dll or any of its dependencies. Moles.exe has to load assembly for execution -- not sure why it does not use Load.RefrectionOnly -- and since moles.exe is ILONLY, it executes as 64 bit process on 64 bit machine. This makes moles generation fail.

The workaround for that is set moles.exe to be 32 bit only:

> corflags moles.exe /Force /32BIT+

(two) If you use parallel build (e.g. in your .msbuild file you have option BuildInParallel="true" , or you run msbuild.exe with option /m) AND you create moles in your unit test project's PreBuildEvent, then you will run into problem with msbuild targets. PreBuildEvent executes before references are resolved, and check for cross-project dependencies are done at the time of resolving references, so there is a chance that your PreBuildEvent will start executing before dependent projects finished building.

There is no good workaround for that. You can either use non-parallel build (which will make your build slower) or you can check in pre-generated *.moles.dll into source control (which you will have to maintain and update every time you touch your moled assembly).

Comment: crap the problem with bounties is that you need to test the answer within the time limit ... and i currently have my release hat on. Its a shame they have time limits that you cant tweak.

Comment: Did and of these suggestions work for anyone then? I tried both but I still keep running into the warning of unresolvable references. In the build directory however the .moles.dll files exist and have, according to their time stamp, been generated during that particular build.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger, it worked for me. You might want to build with MSBuild diagnostic logging turned on to figure out when Moles assembly is produced -- before the compile or after. MSBuild option is `/flp:LogFile=MyLog.log;Verbosity=diagnostic`

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a similar issue with older versions of Moles. Adding disableCache="true" to the .moles file fixed those issues:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/a6d9a67b-0813-4392-a5dd-bea6eb479eea